# Chrome Extension callback function after create tabs not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I create tab then I can't use callback function

```
   document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true,currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: url_homepage, active: true}, function (tabs){
          alert('abc');
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

But it's not working, I try to use `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` like this

```
  document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', function(){
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true,currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: url_homepage, active: true}, function (tabs){
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listenEvent(tabid,info,tab){
        if(info.status == "complete" && tab.url.indexOf(url_homepage) != -1 ){
          alert('abc');
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But it's still not working
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

While creating the new tab just make `active: false` you should be good to go. Use `active: true` when you want to focus to the newly created tab.

also, you don't actually need to query tabs when creating a new tab.

Change this code:

```
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true,currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: url_homepage, active: true}, function (tabs){
          alert('abc');
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

To this should also work.

```
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', function(){
    chrome.tabs.create({url: url_homepage, active: false}, function (tabs){
      alert('abc');
    });
});
```